# p5.js - random(), height, and width not defined?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm trying to make a ball bounce around the canvas using p5.js, but it seems that `width`, `height`, and `random()` aren't defined. 
Here's all my code:

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(640,480);
  background(240);
}

var dot = {
  x: random(width), 
  y: random(height), 
  size: 50,
  r: 255,
  g: 0,
  b: 0,
  speedX: 5,
  speedY: 5
};

function draw() {
  background(240);
  fill(dot.r, dot.g, dot.b);
  ellipse(dot.x, dot.y, dot.size, dot.size);
  if (dot.x >= 615 || dot.x <= 25) { //if the ball is out of screen horizontally
    dot.speedX = dot.speedX * -1;
  } 

  if (dot.y >= 465 || dot.y <= 25) { //if the ball is out of screen vertically
    dot.speedY = dot.speedY * -1;
  }

  dot.x = dot.x + dot.speedX;
  dot.y = dot.y + dot.speedY;
}
```

If I use JavaScript's `Math.random`, it works fine. Furthermore, it works fine if I manually input the width and height as numbers (640 and 480). Shouldn't p5.js automatically assign `height`, `width`, `random`, etc.?
What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use P5.js functions or variables (including `width`, `height`, and `random()`) until **after** `setup()` is called. That's because P5.js isn't loaded yet, so they aren't defined. You have to make sure any calls to P5.js functions or variables are after `setup()` is called.

In your case, you're defining `dot` directly at the top level, which happens at the very beginning, before `setup()` is called. You can test this out by putting `console.println()` calls next to your `dot` definition, and inside the `setup()` function.

To fix this, move the initialization of `dot` to be inside the `setup()` function:

```
var dot;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(640,480);
  
  dot = {
      x: random(width), 
      y: random(height), 
      size: 50,
      r: 255,
      g: 0,
      b: 0,
      speedX: 5,
      speedY: 5
  }

  background(240);
}

function draw() {
  ...
```

You can read more about this in [the P5.js FAQ](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#why-cant-i-assign-variables-using-p5-functions-and-variables-before-setup).