# p5.js - width not defined?

Tags: javascript, web, processing, p5.js

```
var grid;
function setup() {
  createCanvas(800, 800);
  grid = {
    x1: width / 10,
    y1: height / 10,
    x2: width - grid.x1,
    y2: height - grid.y1,
    width: grid.x2 - grid.x1,
    height: grid.y2 - grid.y1,
    margin: grid.width / 10,
    //margin of each lines
  };

  background(255);

}

function draw() {
  grid();
  DDA(grid.x1, grid.y1, grid.margin, grid.margin);
}
// ......
```

[p5.js - random(), height, and width not defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47428208/p5-js-random-height-and-width-not-defined?rq=1)

i saw this question and i changed my code into this but it aint work and there is an error

**"Line 4, col 3: Reassignment of 'grid', which is is a function. Use 'var' or 'let' to declare bindings that may change."**

im using p5.js to make grid graph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, you can't have a variable and a function with the same name. (More confusingly, functions **are** variables!)

Your error is telling you that you have a `grid` variable and a `grid()` function. Do you have a `grid()` function defined somewhere else? If so, just rename the `var grid` to something else, so it stops conflicting with the function.

If you don't have a `grid()` function defined anywhere, then it might be because you're calling `grid()` like a function inside your `draw()` function, which doesn't make sense with the code you've posted. In your code, `grid` is an object, not a function.

If you're still having trouble, please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in a new question post. (The code you posted does **not** show the behavior you're describing, because it's not complete. We should be able to copy-paste your code to see the exact same thing as you.)

Comment: im really thank you for helping Kevin, there was no funtion which named 'grid', anyway i solved this problem in another way. and again im really thank you for helping, next time when i post new question, i will follow ur way. thank you:D

Answer (score 0):

You need in all of the subvariables in the grid variable to be inside a grid start function, like this :

```
grid = {
  start : function(){
    x1: width / 10,
    y1: height / 10,
    x2: width - grid.x1,
    y2: height - grid.y1,
    width: grid.x2 - grid.x1,
    height: grid.y2 - grid.y1,
    margin: grid.width / 10,
    //margin of each lines
  }
};
grid.start();
```

Use this code and replace the old grid variable.